# HTML display two elements inline, able to resize horizontally without wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble aligning two elements on the same line. For example, I have a login form, and I have a username field and a password field. I would like the layout to be like this:

Username: (username field)
Password: (Password field)

I was trying to make it such that the outer div has a max width, let's say 500px. If the window width reduces below 500px, the elements within the div will resize, for example, the username field will resize (at the same time, staying INLINE with the label). However, if I use float or display:inline, it turns out that the username field will wrap below the label before it will resize to a smaller width. Anyway to prevent this effect? I know using a table eliminates this, but I would like to know if there's any way to do it without the use of tables. Also considering usability (div has display:table, but IE7 aren't suitable with the css value.) Please help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap right now, which contains CSS media query, but the included CSS query makes the layout of the controls seem weird, it's like if the resolution falls below 767px then all the controls will go max-width and wrap below their labels.. this is not very nice in presentation though. thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: Well you see, that's the point of a media query. You put something like `@media (max-width: 767px){ selector{ max-width: auto; width: 50% } }`. If that's not going to work for you, then I'm not sure I understand your problem. Could you set up a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bCzgm/

Comment: I added an answer. I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where [calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) comes in handy [(supported by 5 major browsers, but not all mobile)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

We give the labels a static width (I think 110px looks good), find the total margin on the labels (none in this case), and find the total margin on the divs holding the inputs (none in this case). It's also not a bad idea to include a spare 15 or so pixels so that rendering engines have room to be weird (especially with `display: inline-block`).

110px + 0 + 0 + 15px = 125px;

Finally, we would want to add a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to ensure that our changes don't change anything before the problem occurs:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .form-group .col-sm-7 {
        width: calc(100% - 125px);
    }
}
```

Because of the giant style-sheet, there were a few more changes that needed to be made to get [your desired results](http://jsfiddle.net/WwBgw/).

Comment: thanks for the answer! it looks kinda nice, but how is the compatibility with most web browsers as of now? (including mobile)
And also, can the label be made to resize as well? Meaning that I can give it a pretty big width at first, but if the window is resized, the label will resize until the width of the text and stop?

Comment: You're welcome! I linked the browser compatibility chart in my answer, but I'll link to it again here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc Also, the short answer would be "kind of". The labels need to all be the same width so that the inputs line up (else it'd look sloppy). We also need to know the width of the label so that it can be subtracted from the width of the input (or div holding the input in this case). However, if you want to increase the spacing between the text and input, it's easier to give the input div something like `padding-left: 5%` or `padding-left: calc(10px + 5%)` @csharpnewbie

Answer (score 2):

You should use % instead of px or use media queries:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1):

You could set the widths of the inputs as a percentage of the total width. like `width:25%`. You could also wrap each element in a div and set the width on the divs, and 100% width on the inputs. That would be a little more reliable. Here is an example:

```
<div class="form-row" style="max-width:500px;min-width:320px;">
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        Username:
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <input type="text" name="username" style="width:100%;"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" style="max-width:500px;min-width:320px;">
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        Password:
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <input type="password" name="password" style="width:100%;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, the format you gave above makes the entire form appears in the same line :P it should be on two different lines.. anyway, after changing the width of control to 75% it's ok now. But, is there anyway to specify a min-width for the label? I'm doing a website that can cater for mobile devices, and I'm afraid that if the screen is small, the labels will be covered up. I tried entering min-width for the label, but it causes the control to wrap beneath the label...

Comment: My bad, I assumed it was all on one row. I have updated my answer for two rows. And yes, you can add `min-width` to the label. I would actually set a `min-width` on the entire row though, say `320px` for example, which is the width or an iPhone. Then if each div in the row is 50%, the label and the input would both be a minimum of 160px. I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: jproffitt, by adding a min-width to the label, it causes the control after the label to wrap below the label..

Comment: That is why I suggested wrapping each of the label and input in a div and setting 50% width on the divs. Then wrapping those divs with another div and put the min-width on that div. Look at my example above.